# cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails laravel factory

Tags: laravel

I have users table with 20 rows.

When I factored `user_transaction` table, I see this error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fa
> ils (`webafra_testa`.`user_transaction`, CONSTRAINT `user_transaction_userid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: inse
> rt into `user_transaction` (`userId`, `price`, `description`, `type`, `traceableId`, `receptorId`, `status`, `paymentMethod`, `tracking_code`, `created_at`, `update d_at`) values (0, 5, Voluptatem assumenda facilis perferendis nihil est., money_transfer, 1, 1, waiting_payment, online, 1, 2021-05-29 10:41:30, 2021-05-29 10:41:30
> ))'

factory

```
$factory->define(UserTransaction::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'userId' => $faker->randomKey([1, 20]),
        'price' => $faker->randomDigit,
        'description' => $faker->sentence(5),
        'type' => $faker->randomElement(['order', 'sub_factor', 'money_transfer', 'increase_inventory', 'application_fee']),
        'traceableId' => $faker->randomKey([1000, 9999]),
        'receptorId' => $faker->randomKey([1000, 9999]),
        'status' => $faker->randomElement(['done', 'canceled', 'waiting_payment']),
        'paymentMethod' => $faker->randomElement(['tesseke', 'cash', 'online']),
        'tracking_code' => $faker->randomKey([1000, 9999]),
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];
});
```

Comment: check your user id's, that's because there is no users with id in 1 to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'userId' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 20)

also for the others where you used randomKey , change it to numberbetween